# return checkboxes state as a php array

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with checkboxes that I want to receive in Laravel as an array to serialize and save in the database.

That is the way I did:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="car.security.abs" name="security[abs]" ng-model="car.security.abs">
   ABS
   </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="car.security.erd" name="security[erd]" ng-model="car.security.erd">
   Electronic Brake Distribution (EBD)
   </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="car.security.break_assistant" name="security[break_assistant]" ng-model="car.security.break_assistant">
   Brake assistant
   </label>
</div>
```

I get this error when I click on the checkbox:

```
TypeError: can't assign to properties of (new String("s:19:\"s:11:\"s:4:\"true\";\";\";")): not an object
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Now checkboxes work after adding the object in the controller:

`$scope.car.security = [];`

But I don't get the result in the POST request.

Comment: maybe something in your controller, seems that object doesnt exist, show some more code

Comment: I edit the question, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your $scope.car.security is an array you must change it to `$scope.car.security = {};`